# Creating a queue in JavaScript and access global variables in an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I'm not well versed in JavaScript. I have an object below (Foo.bar) that I want to both feed and print items from a queue every 100 ms.

```
var Foo = Foo || {};
Foo.bar = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.feedQueue();
        this.consumeQueue();
    },
    queue: [],
    consumeQueue: function () {
        if (this.queue > 0) {
            var item = this.queue.shift();
            console.log(item);
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.consumeQueue();
        }, 100);
    },
    feedQueue: function () {
        this.queue.push(Math.random());
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.feedQueue();
        }, 100);
    }
};
Foo.bar.initialize();
```

Within the consumeQueue function "this.queue" never updates. It always is empty.

Can anyone help me out here with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Classic _timeout has different context (`this`)_ issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the scope to your timeout functions, otherwise `this` has a different context.

```
setTimeout((function () {
    this.consumeQueue();
}).bind(this), 100);
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cszhhka6/)**</kbd>

Comment: `setTimeout(this.consumeQueue.bind(this), 100)`

Answer (score 4):

why bind, why argument?

```
setTimeout((function () {
    Foo.bar.consumeQueue();
}), 100);
```

Comment: Why downvote? Yes, it should be `Foo.bar` instead of just `Foo`. But it is an [working alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/cszhhka6/1/) (+1)

Comment: Aaaaa.. yes! i not attentive. But what profit for using call or arguments?

Comment: @Deep By using bind or arguments you don't create a closure, that's the only point I can see but your answer deserves an upvote to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797613/creating-a-queue-in-javascript-and-access-global-variables-in-an-anonymous-funct/25797761#comment40351610_25797741

Answer (score 2):

In your callback function `this` is equal to `window` because `this` is omitted when calling the callback.

As [RienNeVaPlus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1650150/riennevaplus) said in his answer you can use bind like this

```
setTimeout((function () {
    this.consumeQueue();
}).bind(this), 100);
```

**OR** you can pass `this` as a parameter to your callack function

```
setTimeout(function (context) {
    context.consumeQueue();
}, 100, this);
```

***In both case if you use IE as a browser, you will need IE9 at least.***

Comment: Maybe. And I'm thinking so TS have only one instance of queue. And more im think so call and arguments create recursive pointers. And this maybe make memleak on IE. in this I am not sure it is necessary to know

Answer (score 1):

As a final alternative to binding or passing it to the callback function, this should work pre IE9:

```
...

consumeQueue: function () {

    if (this.queue > 0) {
        var item = this.queue.shift();
        console.log(item);
    }
    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        that.consumeQueue();
    }, 100);
},

...
```